# Add wsp to solution gallery programmatically

Tags: solution-package

I would like to add a Site template (WSP) to the solution gallery and activate it. TO this, I am using a feature which adds the file but it does not activate and it it looks like just a file that it does not recognise. What could be wrong with my code?

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
            SPWeb rootweb = web.Site.RootWeb;

            SPDocumentLibrary solutionGallery = (SPDocumentLibrary)rootweb.Site.GetCatalog(SPListTemplateType.SolutionCatalog);
            SPFile file = solutionGallery.RootFolder.Files.Add(@"Meeting Template.wsp", File.ReadAllBytes(@"Meeting Template.wsp"));
            SPUserSolution solution = rootweb.Site.Solutions.Add(file.Item.ID);

            rootweb.Features.Add(new Guid("850ECEC2-2D5E-4661-AC78-F133D782561C"), false, SPFeatureDefinitionScope.Site);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ILogger logger = new ULSLogger();
            logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
        }

    }
```

This is my first time trying this out. I put the actual wsp in a Module called Solutions.

Please assist.

Comment: Why not add it with powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Add `file.Update` method to your solution e.g.

```
 SPFile file = solutionGallery.RootFolder.Files.Add(@"Meeting Template.wsp", File.ReadAllBytes(@"Meeting Template.wsp"));
 file.Update();
 SPUserSolution solution = rootweb.Site.Solutions.Add(file.Item.ID);
```